# Is there a 'neat' way to generate Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am trying to write a function that will generate lines of code to create a Puppeteer script. So far, the way I am doing this is by feeding JSON data to a function which processes it and generate a line of code - which is then written to a seperate .JS file.

The problem I am having with this is that I can't write the generated code to a function within this new JS file, so it will obviously throw errors. Is there a better way of generating code to be inserted into a function within another JS file?

```
const generateCode = payload => {
  const { data } = payload;

  var commands = [];

  switch (data[0].action) {
    case 'input':
      // ...
      break;
    case 'click':
      commands.push(`const xpathElement = (await page.$x('${data[0].path}'));`);
      commands.push(`await xpathElement.evaluate( button => button.click() );`);
      break;
    case 'wait':
      // ...
      break;
  }

  writeToTemplate(commands); // writes to file using Node's 'File System'
};
```

Comment: Why can you not write the code to a file? Why would it throw errors?

Comment: Try: `commands.unshift("(async () => {\n"); commands.push("\n})()")`. If you write the array to the file value by value, this will wrap all the commands into a self-executing arrow function.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Sorry I should add, it will throw errors because the file it's being written to has a function to handle the generated code.. so if the code is just written to the end of the file it won't work.

Comment: @LukeFox Oh, I see. But can you not just close the function then when you write the file?

Comment: @Titus Thanks for the suggestion! It works but the problem is I need the generated code to be written inside an existing function, since there is some scaffolding and setup inside the function.

Comment: If you can modify the existing code, you can just add the new code to a function that is called from the existing function in the file.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf You're right, I was considering writing a '}' to the end of the file after the other code had been written. But the issue with that is that until commands are written to the file, the function will be left without the closing bracket. I thought that might be bad practice.

Comment: Something like: `function oldFunction () {.....newFunction()}; function newFunction() {command1;commend2;......}`

Comment: @LukeFox If you fear that a crash of your application might leave the file in an bad state, you can first write everything to a variable and then finally write the variable at once into the file.

Comment: @Titus Thanks, I will give that a go. Does that ultimately mean I will have a function being called that doesn't exist until after the 'newFunction' is generated?

Comment: @LukeFox Yes, you can also define `newFunction` as an empty function and then redefine it when you write the commands to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, you've given me a few more ways of solving this.